# How do you reverse the axis of a Pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I downloaded this CSV from the Covid Tracking Project: https://covidtracking.com/data/download/illinois-history.csv

I am using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('/Users/acan/Downloads')

il_corona = pd.read_csv('illinois-history.csv')
il_corona1 = il_corona[['date', 'death']]
il_corona1.plot()
```

Then I get this plot:

[image]

And curiously enough, the 'date' x axis now only counts how many days ago the date was, although when I ran the script yesterday it had the dates themselves on the x axis from most recent to least recent. So now I have two questions: how can I change the x axis so that it has the actual dates on it and how can I order the x axis so that the line goes up from left to right?

Comment: Please update the question to show the research you've done and exactly where you are stuck after implementing your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.read_csv("https://covidtracking.com/data/download/illinois-history.csv")
df["date"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x:date.fromisoformat(x))
df[['date', 'death']].plot(x="date",y="death")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but I get the error 'NameError: name 'date' is not defined'

Comment: @ACan Ups fixed it

Comment: @ACan sorry I should have included the import. fixed it again